# Как с помощью Hibernate удалить объекты, которые имеют связи ссылающиеся на объекты того же класса?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, spring-data-jpa

Моя сущность имеет поле с дочерними объектами того же типа.
При удалении одного из дочерних элеменов удаляется и родительский.
Как настроить Hibernate и что сделать чтобы при удалении дочерних объектов - родительский объект оставался целым и невредимым?

Моя сущность:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "node")
public class Node extends AbstractEntity {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
  private Node parent;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Node> children;
  
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Comment: Какая схема БД?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если честно, то у меня не получилось с вашим примером воспроизвести поведение при котором при удалении дочернего объекта удалялся бы и родительский.
Я скопировал предоставленную сущность, но при удалении дочерних элементов - родительские оставались в порядке.
Возможно зависит от версии, либо же вы указали в вопросе не все что нужно.

Также есть немалая вероятность в том, что Вы изначально допустили ошибку при проектировании сущностей и того как они будут хранится.

---

Тем не менее в более общем виде я могу дать ответ.

> **Дисклеймер**
> Автор ответа, понимает что описанный ниже способ частенько может(и будет) использоваться в виде костыля.
> *(частенько != всегда и, естественно, есть случаи когда другого выбора просто не будет)*
> Просьба тапками не бросаться и в комментариях написать конкретные предложения, которыми можно улучшить ответ в **данном конкретном случае, с имеющимися в вопросе входными данными**

В общем случае же случае, если ссылки на ваш объект могут быть раскиданы где угодно, ответственность за удаление ссылок на объекты, которые не должны быть каскадом удалены лежит целиком и полностью на вас.

Поставить это "*на поток*" можно с помощью событий жизненного цикла сущности.
При создании, обновлении, получении, удалении объекта, находящегося под контролем EntityManager генерируются события жизненного цикла.

Соответственно Вы можете подписаться на событие генерируемое перед удалением объекта и очистить все ссылки, наличие которых может тем или иным образом навредить при удалении объекта.

Самый простой способ это создать метод непосредственно в классе сущности и пометить его аннотацией `@PreRemove`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "node")
public class Node extends AbstractEntity {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
  private Node parent;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Node> children;
  
  // ...
  @PreRemove
  public void beforeRemoveHandler() {
      this.parent = null;
      // ...
  }
}
```

Соответственно перед удалением данного объекта `Node` будет вызван метод `beforeRemoveHandler()`

---

Если у Вас совсем уже сложный и запущенный случай, в котором Вам нужно будет выполнить глобальную генеральную уборку с доступом к EntityManager'у или же вам нужен будет доступ к другим сервисам (допустим вам после удаления нужно будет отправить сообщение другому компоненту), то в данном случае нужно будет выносить перехват событий из класса сущности в отдельный `EventListener`, в который вы сможете внедрить нужные компоненты.

Для этого вам необходимо создать класс, внедрить в него необходимые зависимости и описать метод, который будет вызываться при удалении объекта

```
public class NodeLifecycleEventListener {
    @Autowired
    NodeRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    SomeService service;
    
    @PreRemove
    public void beforeRemoveHandler(Node node) {
        node.setParent(null);

        Iterable<Node> nodes = repository.findSomeNodesBySomeConditionWithThatNode(node);
        // можете с помощью репозитория найти все объекты 
        // ссылающиеся на вашу ноду и обновить в них ссылки на ваш объект

        // ...
        // и вызвать какой-то сервис для запуска того или иного сценария
        service.someMethod(node);
    }
}
```

После чего вам стоит указать над сущностью аннотацию, которая будет указывать какой именно обработчик событий должен быть у данной сущности

```
@EntityListeners(NodeLifecycleEventListener.class)
```

Будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "node")
@EntityListeners(NodeLifecycleEventListener.class)
public class Node extends AbstractEntity {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
  private Node parent;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Node> children;
  
  // ...
}
```

После чего можно будет пробовать удалять, понимая что у Вас все под контролем.

---

Comment: Здравствуйте! Благодарю за развёрнутый ответ! Забыл уточнить, что в данном примере схема БД создаётся не Hibernate. В случае же, когда схему создаёт сам Hibernate, то все работает без проблем.